# Unity crouching

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey) && isCrouching == false )
    {
        YCrouched();            
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey) && isCrouching == true && isInCeiling == false)
    {
        NCrouched();
    }    
}

void YCrouched()
{
    isCrouching = true;
    controller.height = 1f;
    player.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.8f, crouchHeight, 0.8f);
    moveSpeed = crouchSpeed;
}
void NCrouched()
{
    isCrouching = false;
    controller.height = 2f;
    player.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    moveSpeed = deafultSpeed;
}
```

So the problem is when ever i am coming out of a area like a vent where there is ceiling above i still stay crouched. And only when i press crouch again do i come back up.

Comment: So remove the check for the player releasing the key?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be to check if the inCeiling status has changed from the previous update. Try adding the following

```
//keeps the previous state of isInCeiling, add this to wherever isInCeiling is defined.
bool wasInCeiling

//add this check to your list of if-checks
if(wasInCeiling == true && isInCeiling == false) 
{
    NCrouched() ;
}
```

That should make the player automatically stand up whenever and only when he comes out of the ceiling.

Also you need to add a bit to your update code, so that on every update you first set the current isInCeiling value to wasInCeiling and then perform the check for current status of isInCeiling. That should always keep wasInCeiling one frame behind isInCeiling.

Comment: Glad it helped! Remember to mark answer as correct if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey) && isCrouching == true && isInCeiling == false)
{
    NCrouched();
}
```

Change to

```
if (isCrouching == true && isInCeiling == false)
{
    NCrouched();
}
```

Assuming you are tracking isInCeilling